# page call ajax another subpage and this subpage call another subpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 3 page: page1.php page2.php page3.php
page1.php has ajax and is calling page2.php.
page2.php has php and javascript code and if everything is correct ajax calls page3.php that registers everything in mysql.

There is only one problem. I think an ajax call to a sub page, this sub page cannot call another sub page is it correct?

Each separate page works wonders.
but page2.php is not able to call by ajax when it is called by ajax.

page1.php

```
    <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation6() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition6, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition6(position) {


    var latfinal=position.coords.latitude;
            var longfinal=position.coords.longitude;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latfinal, longfinal);
            var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        var Var_JavaScript = results[1].formatted_address;

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "insert-fichaje2.php?lat="+latfinal+"&long="+longfinal+"&status=ReanudarTransporte&usuario=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>&direccion="+Var_JavaScript +"&empresa=<?php echo $empresa;?>",
                                dataType: "json",
                                    success: function() {

                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "page2.php?lat="+latfinal+"&long="+longfinal+"&status=ReanudarTransporte&usuario=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>&direccion="+Var_JavaScript +"&empresa=<?php echo $empresa;?>",
                                            dataType: "json",

                                        });

                                        alert("Cambio con exito!");
                                            location.reload();

                                    },
                                    error: function() {
                                        alert(" ERROR!!!");
                                            location.reload();
                                    }

                            });
                    }

                }

            });


    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "";
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
    alert("Has detenido acceso a tu ubicacion. Porfavor dame permiso a tu ubicacion!");
      x.innerHTML = "Has detenido acceso a tu ubicacion. Porfavor dame permiso a tu ubicacion."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "No tengo tu ubicacion"
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "A aparesido un error."
      break;
  }
}
</script>
```

page2.php intenta ver si la ubicacion esta dentro de los circulos permitido y va llamar a otra pagina para introducir si es o no dentro del circulo.

```
       <script>
    window.onload = function init() {

        var monitorzonafichaje = "<?php echo $avisosficahejzonas;?>";
        var monitorzonanave = "<?php echo $fichajefueranave;?>";
        var monitorzonapunctos = "<?php echo $fichajefuerapunctos;?>";



        var latempresa= "<?php echo $latempresa;?>";
        var longempresa= "<?php echo $longempresa;?>";
        var latuser ="<?php echo $lat;?>";
        var longuser = "<?php echo $long;?>";

        if (monitorzonafichaje === "1"){
            if (monitorzonanave === "1"){
                var
                    contentCenter = '<span class="infowin">Center Marker (draggable)</span>',
                            contentCenter2 = '<span class="infowin">Center2 Marker (draggable)</span>',
                    contentA = '<span class="infowin">Marker A (draggable)</span>',
                    contentB = '<span class="infowin">Marker B (draggable)</span>';
                var
                    latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latempresa, longempresa),
                    latLngCMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(latempresa, longempresa),
                        latLngCMarker2 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.0814, -93.5105),
                    latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(latuser, longuser),
                    latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -93),
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 7,
                        center: latLngCenter,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: false
                    }),
                    markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLngCMarker,
                        title: 'Location',
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true
                    }),
                            markerCenter2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latLngCMarker2,
                                title: 'Location',
                                map: map,
                                draggable: true
                            }),
                    infoCenter = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentCenter
                    }),

                    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLngA,
                        title: 'Location',
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true
                    }),
                    infoA = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentA
                    }),
                    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLngB,
                        title: 'Location',
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true
                    }),
                    infoB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentB
                    })
                    // exemplary setup: 
                    // Assumes that your map is signed to the var "map"
                    // Also assumes that your marker is named "marker"
                    ,
                    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        map: map,
                        clickable: false,
                        // metres
                        radius: 100,
                        fillColor: '#fff',
                        fillOpacity: .6,
                        strokeColor: '#313131',
                        strokeOpacity: .4,
                        strokeWeight: .8
                    });

                    circle2 = new google.maps.Circle({
                        map: map,
                        clickable: false,
                        // metres
                        radius: 100000,
                        fillColor: '#fff',
                        fillOpacity: .6,
                        strokeColor: '#313131',
                        strokeOpacity: .4,
                        strokeWeight: .8
                    });

                // attach circle to marker
                circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');
                     circle2.bindTo('center', markerCenter2, 'position');

                var
                // get the Bounds of the circle
                bounds = circle.getBounds()
                 bounds2 = circle2.getBounds()
                // Note spans
                ,
                    noteA = jQuery('.bool#a'),
                    noteB = jQuery('.bool#b');

              var myvar = bounds.contains(latLngA);


            if (!myvar){

                $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "page3.php?dentro=no",
                                            dataType: "json",

                                        });
            }else{
$.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "page3.php?dentro=yes",
                                            dataType: "json",

                                        });
            }   
            //--------
            }else{
                if (monitorzonapunctos === "1"){

                }
            }
        }


    };
    </script>
```

and page3.php is php insert mysql.

Comment: You can chain ajax calls or you can have the php in page2.php call page3.php. I don't really get what your are trying to do, XHR is simply a way of communicating from client to server, the rest is up to you.

Comment: e agregado el código para que entendemos mejor

Comment: hi, i can't make an ajax call on another. Is it possible that the server has some restriction so that subpages cannot call other subpages?

Comment: Okay I think i understand. When you make an ajax call the javascript runs in your browser. When you query another page using xhr the html result isn't interpreted by your browser so any javascript in the page won't have any effect unless evaluated using specific code but this is'nt a good way to handle anything. In most cases your ajax call should'nt be calling an html page. In your case I'm guessing you just want to fire some php from page3.php. One approach would be to split your php code and include the script from page3.php in page2.php to fire it.

Comment: that is, page 1 generates the data, which activates page 2 by ajax call, and if everything is correct you have to call page 3 php to enter the data in mysql.but page 2, it is not able to call page 3, but if I activate in browser page2 if it activates page3.php, then I wanted to know if this is normal or because of my server that uses Centos Web Panel and it can be as a limit of This server.

Comment: This is the way ajax works. When you make an ajax call you are only querying data. You need to distinguish server code from client code.